# How to pass full user name to saslauthd from postfix

Tags: postfix, saslauthd

I'm trying to configure postfix for SMTP Auth using Cyrus `saslauthd` and an `rimap` configuration.  I have it working, except for the fact that, due to virtual domains, the auth username for my IMAP installation uses full email addresses (`foo@example.com`), but postfix (or perhaps saslauthd?) is removing the domain name when sending the auth request to the IMAP server.

From `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
May  7 10:54:02 xxx postfix/smtpd[25564]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
May  7 10:54:02 xxx postfix/smtpd[25564]: warning: 108-71-0-101.lightspeed.lsvlky.sbcglobal.net[108.71.0.101]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
May  7 10:54:02 xxx imapd: Disconnected, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1], time=5
May  7 10:54:02 xxx imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
May  7 10:54:02 xxx imapd: LOGIN FAILED, user=foo, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
```

Notice on the last line, `LOGIN FAILED, user=foo`, and not `foo@example.com`.

I have verified that my saslauthd is working with the full address from the command line:

```
# testsaslauthd -u foo@example.com -p abc123
0: OK "Success."
# testsaslauthd -u foo -p abc123
0: NO "authentication failed"
```

Is there any way to use the full email address here?